# Failsafe Coding

Tags: php

The question rises when the person accessing a website, does not or can not complete a server process. Like photo uploading, registering, blogging, or other.

The reasons behind it? Where to get started

- Slow system
- Slow or disruptive internet connections
- Sudden restart
- Sudden page close

Now, my question is, What are the best measures to deal with this?

- What are the steps that has to be taken, from our <sub>(developer)</sub> side to make a program as fail safe as possible?

And, even after our side to completely covered. What are the measures that has to be applied to prevent or minimize the damage due to visitor?

Comment: define "damage" and your answer lies in usage of transactions and rollbacks if transactions happen to fail. Also garbage collection is pretty well known term and widely used to erase whatever goes wrong

Comment: Apache and PHP handle 99.9% of these situations.

Comment: @Anton S, damage generally refers to incomplete process completion. Like, a article upload takes place in three stages, article entry to database, images upload and attachments upload, updating the database entry about the images and file upload. Now, if any of this process breaks in middle, it create damages, like article with no image. etc.... I hope you get my point.

Comment: @Anne, its good to hear about that, but what are measures that developers can take to avoid that 0.1% gap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your primary concern is a clean database then you probably want to utilize transactions. Transactions only get committed if all queries are succesful, otherwise they are rolled back.

If user experience matters to you, you will probably want to store data gathered from intermediary steps in temporary tables (drafts) and check the data for sanity before committing them to the live tables (again use transactions here). That way the user doesn't lose his work and can re-submit the data when the issue on his (or your) side has been resolved. Using AJAX you can do this even before forms are submitted, although you have to decide whether the added usability is worth the impact on the server (e.g. cpu load and storage).

Comment: Thanks, for your suggestions about transactions. I am learning about them right now. Can you give me some references BTW?